# return text/html content-type when using flask-restful

Tags: python, httpresponse, content-type, flask-restful

In a specific case I'd like to respond with a `text/html` content-type for an error as follows:

```
class MyResource(Resource):
    def get(self):
        if some_condition:
            return 'bad argument', 400
```

The code above returns an `application/json` content-type: `'"bad argument"'`
instead of a `text/html` content-type: `'bad argument'`

How can I force flask-restful to respond with `text/html` content-type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to use [`flask.make_response()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.make_response) to return a 'pre-baked' response object:

```
return flask.make_response('bad argument', 400)
```

Flask-Restful will pass full-on `Response` objects unaltered, rather than try and convert them to a specific requested mime type.